# How to license P2V OEM Windows 7 with a retail license with VMware Fusion?

Tags: windows-7, license, vmware-fusion

A friend of mine did a P2V of his Acer physical Windows 7 Home Premium to run on his Mac using VMware Fusion.

Now the VM complains it is not properly licensed. Microsoft is directing him to Acer, and Acer to Microsoft.

In the mean time, he bought a new retail Windows 7 Home Premium License and Media, but doesn't want to reinstall his machine. However that license does not work; he gets a Dutch message (that has an error code `0xC004C008` when going to "Details") which I've tried to translate.

- Dutch

  - Geef een andere productcode voor activeren op.
    De opgegeven productcode kan niet worden gebruikt om Windows op deze computer te activeren.
- English

  - Enter a different product code to activate.
    The entered product code cannot be used to activate Windows on this computer.

What ways are there to get this machine properly licensed?

Comment: The language on both are exactly the same correct?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, the language and edition (Windows 7 Home Premium) are both the same. What I suspect is that the OEM is hardware locked to the motherboard, and somehow the retail key cannot undo that.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers - There is no reason you would be unable to change the license from an OEM Windows 7 Home Premium License to a retail Windows 7 Home Premium License.  Does Windows accept the new license?  If it does then you should be able to activate it.  If you can't use the online activation use the phone activation.  I had to do that when I transfered a Windows 8.0 WMC license to another machine, changed the license, I then had to manual activation because the WMC key had already been activated on VM ( which was then deleted because its sole purpose was to purchase the WMC upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. I'll pass this on and report back the result.